# Automatically activate sharepoint framework extension on all subsites(modern pages)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I want to use simple js script on my intranet Sharepoint Online modern page. I used [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/serving-your-extension-from-sharepoint) and everything works decent, but when I create subsite mine js script just does attach. How could I attach it to all subsites? Is there any option to automatically attach it when creating subsite?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the global deployment option for your extension component.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMyZHtE5IbI&feature=youtu.be&t=1011) is official demo for your reference.

Comment: I tried it, but when I added a new row to mine TenantWideExtensions list nothing changes, where could I made a mistake? Is there any different way to achieve my goal?